# Meaning of "Eres touch?"

Tags: modismos

Saw this on Facebook today... what does it mean?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's Spanglish for "Are you (a) touch (device)?" (like a touch screen). In other words "Do you respond to tactile manipulation?"